# Excel VLOOKUP N/A error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table setup like this:

[image]

I am trying to do a lookup, where Column D value matched one of the Column A values and returns Column C value.

The numbers in column A and D are stored as text.

My formula is `VLOOKUP(F3,A1:C3,3,TRUE)` but this returns "Value not available error". What is wrong with the formula?

**EDIT**

Figured out that some of the values were stored as general.

Now the problem is that I have to get an exact match with leading zeroes. 
For example in Column D I have "27154" but in Column A I have "000027154", these should match.

But if I have "000271540"  or any other variant in Column A, it should not match.

All the numbers in Column A are 9 digits long with leading zeroes where needed.

Comment: 458754 is not in column A of your sample data so how are we supposed to match that if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @user2140261 F3 not F2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
VLOOKUP(TEXT(F3, "000000000"),A1:C3,3,FALSE)
```

It will require creating the same value for the `VLOOKUP` to find the value. Looking at your example, the length of the text in column A is 9 characters. As a result, the padding is applied which will be used to search. To make it exact match, `FALSE` is used as last argument to `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: This gives me mixed results, I am not sure why yet. With this I still get some as N/A and others as "0" when in reality they still have a value in the 3rd column

Comment: Can you post an example please?

Comment: Thanks its ok, I will manually add in the rest as there arent many and  I need to get this done ASAP

Answer (score 4):

You can use wildcards in `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&F3,A2:C3,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried this as well, can you read my comment under shahkalpeshs answer? as I get the same results.

Comment: This works with your example given. As shahkalpesh says, can we see an example where it's **not** working?

Comment: The wildcard could be dangerous if Column A had a value of say 000327154 that would still match to 27154, I don't think that's what the OA is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the formula. The problem is that the value in A2 is text and treated as text when comparing to the number in F3.

If you can't change your values in column A, then you can use this array formula:

```
=SUM((F3=VALUE(A2:A3))*(C2:C3))
```

Enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

This will convert the values in A2:A3 as numbers for the comparison against F3.